# Node.js não carrega scripts js nem css

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

Estou fazendo uma app de chat e consigo ir buscar a página que quero mas essa página não carrega os css correspondentes nem os scripts js, alguém tem alguma solução para isto por favor? Até agora tenho isto:

Código:

server.js:

```
var socket  = require( './node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./node_modules/express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var users = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', 'isto veio do server: ' +msg);
  });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
});
```

index.html:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/estilos.css"> <!-- este não carrega -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/funcs.js"></script> <!-- este não carrega -->
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de configurar no teu `server.js` uma diretoria base para que os html consigam dar uso aos recursos. Põe isto a seguir de `var users = []` e vê se resulta:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```